# What uses the sha256 implementation of the Linux kernel?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

I'm willing to implement a faster sha256 on the Linux kernel for a specific architecture but I'm not aware of what uses it.

I'm not only interested in user-space software using the kernel APIs but also kernel-space functionalities that re-uses the sha256 cryptographic algorithm.

Comment: You would easily find users by running `git grep -n $FUNCTION_NAME`.

Answer (score 1):

[`sha256_generic.c`](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/crypto/sha256_generic.c) contains a platform-independent implementation of sha256 implementation in the kernel.

I guess you could trace the locations where it is used in Kernel starting from this file, but it is hard to come up with a complete list.

You find sha256 used mostly in the network stack, for instance:

- HMAC: Keyed-Hashing for Message Authentication (RFC2104). (Required for IPSec.)

When it comes to user-space, I'm not sure if the kernel's sha256 is heavily used. For instance, I had a look at the `sha256sum` utility, which is part of coreutils. If I read the source code correctly, it uses the sha256 implementation of openssl instead.